# form validation - focus on 'error' input

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm showing error messages/ alerts for a registration form, which point to the input with the error.

I want to focus on this error input, too.

However, my code currently focuses on the last input?

heres a link. to recreate, simply click register without filling anything in. the error displays for the first div... but focuses on the last.

[link](http://ry-design.co.uk/includes/register.php)

my code currently:

```
$('#register-btn').on('click', checkEmpty);

function checkEmpty(){
    var emptyDiv = $('.add-listing-input').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).val() == "";
    });

    if(emptyDiv.length > 0){
        var theTop = emptyDiv.position();
        var theBottom = theTop.top + emptyDiv.height() +25;
        var theText = emptyDiv.attr('id');
        $('#register-errors').css('top',theBottom+'px').show();
        $('#error-text').text('Your '+theText+' is missing, please fill in');
        emptyDiv.focus();
        emptyDiv.on('keydown', function(){
                $('#register-errors').hide();
                $('#error-text').text('');

        });
    }else{
        $('#register-errors').hide();
        $('#error-text').text('');
        checkEmails()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `emptyDiv` is actually a collection of all empty fields, saying something like `emptyDiv.focus()` will try to focus on all of them (which isn't possible) and apparently just focuses the last one instead.

Try using the `.first()` method to filter it down to exactly what you want: `emptyDiv.first().focus()`

Here's my suggested re-write:

```
//Select some elements once
var $registerErrors = $('#register-errors');
var $errorsMsg = $('#error-text');

//click the registed button
$('#register-btn').click(function(){
    var $emptyInputs = $('.add-listing-input').filter(function() { 
        return this.value == "";
    });

    if($emptyInputs){
        var $firstEmptyInput = $emptyInputs.first();

        var bottomPosition = $firstEmptyInput.position().top + $firstEmptyInput.height() +25;
        var inputId = $firstEmptyInput.attr('id');

        $registerErrors
            .css('top', bottomPosition)
            .show();

        $errorsMsg.text('Your '+ inputId +' is missing, please fill in');

        $firstEmptyInput
            .focus()
            .one('keydown', clearError); //this event only fires once!
    }else{
        clearError();
        checkEmails();
    }
});

function clearError(){
    $registerErrors.hide();
    $errorsMsg.text('');
}
```